# Unable to reference ListView while using ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I'm trying to populate a ListView using JSON but I'm running into trouble referencing the ListView.

Here is my layout_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp">


<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />


<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="No data"        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I read on the ListFragment documentation that when designing a custom list, I need to keep the ListView's id as "@id/android:list".

Here is the piece of code that I am having problems with:

```
list = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
```

I currently have that code in my JSON parsing method but I have tried putting it in my public View onCreateView method according to other suggestions that I read online, but I still get the following error:

```
Cannot Resolve symbol 'list'
```

Would anyone be able to help clear up my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `ListFragment` includes a listview and adapter inside it, and  also provides some methods that allow you to get the listview and operate on it.

You can refer to it (from the ListFragment) in this way:

```
getListView()
```

You need to refer to the `android:id="@id/android:list"` only if you want customize the layout. In this case you need to override the `onCreateView` method, and then refer to the list element `"@android:id/list"`

```
(ListView)getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list)
```

and

```
getListView()
```

are the same things. But you don't need to use the first expression, except if you want customize the `ListView` inside the `ListFragment`

Comment: I've tried using getListView() but it still gives me the same error. I've tried using list = getListView() and list = (ListView)getListView().findViewById(R.id.list); Neither of them work.

Comment: no, you don't need to get `ListView` reference from layout. You already have a listview, you just need to get the reference using `getListView()`

Comment: I've tried to call  getListView()  in the JSON Parsing method and in my  onActivityCreated. When I put it in onCreateView, it crashes the app.

Comment: You have to use `getListView()` inside you fragment. For example if you want set a listener for the items inside your list, call: `getListView().setOnItemClickListener(...);`

Comment: So I've tried: getListView().findViewById(R.id.list), but it still says that I can't find the symbol "list". It only gives me the options for my List_items_row.xml and not my Layout_main.xml (file i want to reference). Thanks for having patience with me

Comment: No, it is wrong. The motivataion for use a ListFragment is that you don't need to worry about the creation of a layout and reference fot ListView. ListFragment already provides you a listview. You can refer to it with getListView(). I edited the answer.

Comment: So am I correct in assuming that in order to customise my ListView, I'll need to use "(ListView)getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list)"?

Comment: Yes, if you want customize it, you can get the reference to the list in that way, and modify it (inside onCreateView)

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thanks very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
list = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
```

do you use your application R or android's R? try to code like this:

```
list = (ListView)getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've tried using Android.R.id.list but no luck. It's still broken.